# Speed up solution for "ProjectEuler 35: Circular primes count below 1 million"

Tags: ruby, performance

A number is called a circular prime if all of it's rotations are primes themselves.

For example the number 197 has two rotations: 971, and 719. Both of them are prime.

There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.

How many circular primes are there below N?

1 <= N <= 1000000

```
require 'prime'
require 'benchmark'

def circular_prime_count(kk)
   primes = []
   count = 0
   Prime.each(kk) do |prime|
    pa= prime.to_s.split('')
    flag = true
    pa.count.times do |i|
      pa.rotate!
      flag = false if !Prime.prime?(pa.join.to_i)
    end 
    count+=1 if flag
   end
   count
end

[100, 200, 1000, 2000 ,10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000 ].each do |number|
  puts "Count of primes below #{number} is: #{circular_prime_count(number)}"
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report do 
      circular_prime_count(number)
    end
  end  
end
```

My benchmark on ruby 2.0.0p247 is:

count of primes below 100 is: 13

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001891)
```

count of primes below 200 is: 17

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004775)
```

count of primes below 1000 is: 25

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.005716)
```

count of primes below 2000 is: 27

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.018399)
```

count of primes below 10000 is: 33

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.105365)
```

count of primes below 100000 is: 43

```
       user     system      total        real
   1.790000   0.000000   1.790000 (  1.789223)
```

count of primes below 1000000 is: 55

```
       user     system      total        real
  43.870000   0.010000  43.880000 ( 43.971832)
```

**Could you help to improve performance to find count for 1 million for 20 seconds?**

My notebook model is:  HP Probook 4530s

Processor Information:

Family: Core i5

Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation

ID: A7 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF

Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz

Voltage: 1.2 V

External Clock: 100 MHz

Max Speed: 2500 MHz

Current Speed: 2500 MHz

Status: Populated, Enabled

Core Count: 2

Core Enabled: 2

Thread Count: 4

Thanks everyone, so final solution is:

```
require 'prime'
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'
def circular_prime_count_v2(search_max)
    max = if search_max == 10 ** (search_max.to_s.length - 1)
      search_max
    else
      10 ** search_max.to_s.length - 1 
    end
    primes = Prime.each(max).to_set
    count = 0
    primes.each do |prime|
      break if prime > search_max
      s = prime.to_s
      l = s.length
      l.times { |i| primes.include?(((s * 2)[i, l]).to_i) || break } || next
      count+=1
    end
    count
end
[100, 200, 1000, 2000 ,10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000 ].each do |number|
  puts "Count of primes below #{number} is: #{circular_prime_count_v2(number)}"
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report('circular_prime_count') do 
      circular_prime_count_v2(number)
    end
  end  
end
```

Count of primes below 100 is: 13

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000482)
```

Count of primes below 200 is: 17

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002683)
```

Count of primes below 1000 is: 25

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003666)
```

Count of primes below 2000 is: 27

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.005241)
```

Count of primes below 10000 is: 33

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.007074)
```

Count of primes below 100000 is: 43

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.057128)
```

Count of primes below 1000000 is: 55

```
   user     system      total        real

circular_prime_count  0.720000   0.000000   0.720000 (  0.727345)
```

Comment: Perhaps belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Help to change article for this place.

Comment: Looks like you are pretty close to your target number - getting machine that is twice as fast should be enough. If you need software solution and are sure you pick the best known algorithm - profile and than add this information to the post. Side note: Since you've solved to problem you may be able to find help on forums where you got it from - http://projecteuler.net/problem=35

Comment: Hmm. You need 2x performance.. and you have 2 cores.. This number keeps repeating, I wonder if there's any connection here..

Comment: ruby uses 1 core per process. ruby is not Jruby.

Comment: Well i'm no expert, I just saw stuff like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574905/ruby-1-9-3-multicore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I have created a MUCH faster implementation.  For historic value, it was roughly based on [this post](http://www.technicalypto.com/2010/08/project-euler-how-many-circular-primes.html).  From my basic testing(with 1 million records), its about 40 times faster than the original.

```
require 'prime'
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

def circular_prime_count(kk)
  primes, count = [], 0
  Prime.each(kk) do |prime|
    pa= prime.to_s.split('')
    flag = true
    pa.count.times do |i|
      pa.rotate!
      flag = false if !Prime.prime?(pa.join.to_i)
    end 
    count+=1 if flag
  end
  count
end

def circular_prime_count_v2(search_max)
    primes = Prime.each(search_max).to_set
    count = 0
    primes.each do |prime|
      str = prime.to_s
      all_points_match = (0...str.length).collect { |i| primes.include?(((str * 2)[i, str.length]).to_i) || break }
      count+=1 if all_points_match
    end
    count
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('circular_prime_count') do 
    puts " Count: #{circular_prime_count(1000000)}"
  end

  x.report('circular_prime_count_v2') do
    puts " Count: #{circular_prime_count_v2(1000000)}"
  end
end
```

**NEW RESULTS**

```
       user     system      total        real
circular_prime_count Count: 55
 39.430000   0.080000  39.510000 ( 39.603969)
circular_prime_count_v2 Count: 55
  0.900000   0.000000   0.900000 (  0.906725)
```

Comment: user     system      total        real
  40.740000   0.000000  40.740000 ( 40.852501)
  21.290000   0.000000  21.290000 ( 21.336877) 
pretty fast

thanks MAN.

Comment: @SergeyKutsko I have edited my answer.  It turns out the ruby prime implementation is much faster than hand rolling it.  I'm curious to see your speed improvements.

Comment: You combined 2 solutions and time on my machine is: ( 15.535589)
AWESOME!!

Comment: @SergeyKutsko Awesome.  I'm sure there are still improvements to be made but that should be a good start.

Comment: @SergeyKutsko I updated one one more time, can you run the latest code?

Comment: It is fast, but wrong answers for 200, 2000

Comment: edit your function acording rigth values for 200 count is 17 fir 2000 is 27